# How Nested Find MongoDB ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How to nested find in mongodb with collection data below :

```
{
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "585b998297f53460d5f760e6"
 },
 "newspaper": {
  "playerID": "57bffe76b6a70d6e2a3855b7",
  "playerUsername": "dennis",
  "player_newspaper": "{\"ID\":\"57bffe76b6a70d6e2a3855b7\",\"Username\":\"Dennis\",\"itemName\":\"Corn\",\"Comment\":\"Jagung Promo\",\"Date\":\"12/27/2016\"}"
 }
}
```

My code :

```
var datex = new Date();
var dates = datex.getMonth() + '/' + datex.getDate() + '/' + datex.getFullYear();
db.playerNewspaper.remove( {"newspaper.player_newspaper.Date": dates } } } ) ;
```

This is not working.

and

That's how I insert the data:

```
var currentPlayer = {
        "playerID": playerID,
        "playerUsername": playerUsername,
        "player_newspaper": newspaper

    }; // we construct a new player from the data we are about to input into the player data

    playerDataList.insert(
    {
      "newspaper" : currentPlayer
    } // Uses the $set mongo modifier to set old player data to the current player data
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks good but problem in your data. According to your query condition you assume that `player_newspaper` is an `object` but that data you shown there `player_newspaper` is a `String`. So in your query `"newspaper.player_newspaper.Date": date` not found any document that's why query not working.

Your document structure should be like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("585b998297f53460d5f760e6"),
    "newspaper" : {
        "playerID" : "57bffe76b6a70d6e2a3855b7",
        "playerUsername" : "dennis",
        "player_newspaper" : {
            "ID" : "57bffe76b6a70d6e2a3855b7",
            "Username" : "Dennis",
            "itemName" : "Corn",
            "Comment" : "Jagung Promo",
            "Date" : "12/27/2016"
        }
    }
}
```

Then your query will be working fine.

```
var datex = new Date();
var dates = datex.getMonth() + '/' + datex.getDate() + '/' + datex.getFullYear();
db.playerNewspaper.remove( {"newspaper.player_newspaper.Date": dates } } } ) ;
```

Comment: Hi @shaisab, So what the query will look like if the data if like mine ?

Comment: Well, I think you should change your data structure. That's not a valid structure or unfortunately you did that while updating or adding. @DennisLiu

Comment: So how to insert a data with a structure like yours ?

Comment: How get `newpaper` in `"player_newspaper": newspaper` ? check that structure

Comment: "player_newspaper": newspaper
That newspaper is a class that i convert to json string.

Comment: that should convert to json object not json string

Comment: What about if I type :  playerDataList.insert(
    {
      currentPlayer
    } // Uses the $set mongo modifier to set old player data to the current player data
    ); Like this is this valid ?

Comment: my data "{\"ID\":\"57bffe76b6a70d6e2a3855b7\",\"Username\":\"Dennis\",\"itemName\":\"Corn\",\"Comment\":\"Jagung Promo\",\"Date\":\"12/27/2016\"}" That is a string. Do you have any idea to get Date: 12/27/2016 ? If i do : {"newspaper.player_newspaper": <getdate : 12/27/2016 (what is in here should get the date> } ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131665/discussion-between-shaishab-roy-and-dennis-liu).